# How do I copy and insert rows to a master sheet, and place these multiple rows in different locations based on keywords found on the master sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is the current code I'm running.

```
Sub PullTally()
 ' get source and destination workbook files
    Dim pullFile As String
    pullFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")  'Copy From'
    Dim putFile As String
    putFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilter:="All Files (* . *) , * . * ")   'Insert To'
    'open source workbook
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=pullFile)
    ' open destination workbook
    Dim DestWb As Workbook
    Set DestWb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=putFile)

Dim destWS As Worksheet:  destWS = DestWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim sourceWS As Worksheet:  sourceWS = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim sourceRowNum As Long
For sourceRowNum = 1 To 13 Step 1
    With sourceWS
        Dim findTerm As String
        Select Case True
            Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(OUTSOURCED)"
                findTerm = "OUTSOURCED"
            Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "No"
                findTerm = "COMING UP…"
            Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(DESIGN ONLY)"
                findTerm = "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
            Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "Yes"
                findTerm = "DESIGN;PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
            Case Else
            'can add other cases
        End Select
    End With
    With destWS
        Dim findRange As Range
        Set findRange = .Columns(1).Find(findTerm)
        If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
            Dim destInsertRow As Long
            If findRange.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
                destInsertRow = findRange.Row + 1
            Else
                destInsertRow = findRange.End(xlDown).Row + 1
            End If
            sourceWS.Rows(sourceRowNum).Copy
            destWS.Rows(destInsertRow).Insert xlDown
        End If
    End With
Next sourceRowNum

End Sub
```

Currently, It takes the whole block of information in K4:M19 on the subsheet , inserts 13 rows on the master @ A60, and copy/pastes K4:M19(sub) @ A60(master). (There are normally many blank rows that it copies over which I'm not sure how to eliminate with the current code setup.)

I'd like it to search the master sheet for specific text like:

```
"DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
"DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
"OUTSOURCED"
"COMING UP…"
```

and insert the copied SourceWb rows under these keywords on the DestWb based on the information in the SourceWb row. For example, if row 4 needs Design ("Yes" in column E), the row should be inserted under "DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS" on the master workbook.

The DestWb keywords relate to SourceWb like so:

```
"DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS" - SourceWb, Column E: "Yes" AND Column D: <> "(DESIGN ONLY)" 
"DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"       - SourceWb, Column D: "(DESIGN ONLY)" 
"OUTSOURCED"                       - SourceWb, Column D: "(OUTSOURCED)" 
"COMING UP…"                       - SourceWb, Column E: "No"
```

[image: Example of DestWb information and format]
[image: Example of SourceWb information and format]

I'm thinking it will need a vlookup() and loop for each row? As I am a complete novice, I have no clue what I'm doing and all I'm good for is Frankenstein-ing multiple codes together from stackoverflow...

I appreciate any help anyone can lend me.

Comment: You're just wanting to insert one row from the source sheet into the destination sheet under the appropriate header?

Comment: I'm looking to insert multiple rows under the correct header. The range for rows that might have information in them are A4:H19.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can work out your own cases of logic (for each "DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS", "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS", "OUTSOURCED", "COMING UP…"), you could do something like this:

```
'untested
dim sourceWS as worksheet:  destWS = destWB.Sheets(name1)
dim destWS as worksheet:  sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets(name2)
dim sourceRowNum as long
for sourceRowNum = 1 to 10 step 1
    with sourceWS
        dim findTerm as string
        select case true
            case .cells(sourceRowNum,5).value = "Yes"
                findTerm = "DESIGN; PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
            case else
                'can add other cases
        end select
    end with
    with destWS
        dim findRange as range
        set findRange = .columns(1).find(findTerm)
        if not findRange is nothing then
            dim destInsertRow as long
            if findRange.offset(1).value = "" then 
                destInsertRow = findRange.Row+1
            else
                destInsertRow = findRange.end(xldown).row+1
            end if
            sourceWS.rows(sourceRowNum).copy
            destWS.rows(destInsertRow).insert xldown
        end if
    end with
next sourceRowNum
```

---

Edit1:  Verified that OP's modified code from above works... here is my use of the code, which does work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PullTally()
'###
    Dim SourceWb As Workbook
    Set SourceWb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim DestWb As Workbook
    Set DestWb = ThisWorkbook
'###
    Dim destWS As Worksheet:  Set destWS = DestWb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet:  Set sourceWS = SourceWb.Worksheets(2)
    Dim sourceRowNum As Long
    For sourceRowNum = 1 To 13 Step 1
        With sourceWS
            Dim findTerm As String
            Select Case True
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(OUTSOURCED)"
                    findTerm = "OUTSOURCED"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "No"
                    findTerm = "COMING UP…"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(DESIGN ONLY)"
                    findTerm = "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
                Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "Yes"
                    findTerm = "DESIGN;PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"
                Case Else
                'can add other cases
            End Select
        End With
        With destWS
            Dim findRange As Range
            Set findRange = .Columns(1).Find(findTerm)
            If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                Dim destInsertRow As Long
                If findRange.Offset(1).Value = "" Then
                    destInsertRow = findRange.Row + 1
                Else
                    destInsertRow = findRange.End(xlDown).Row + 1
                End If
                sourceWS.Rows(sourceRowNum).Copy
                destWS.Rows(destInsertRow).Insert xlDown
            End If
        End With
    Next sourceRowNum
End Sub
```

My destination/sheet1 output after running code:

[image]

My source/sheet2 data being used (looks like you may want to add lines for skipping blank rows):

[image]

Comment: It's giving a compile error for the first case else "Case without Select Case" after i've added 3 else to the code.

Comment: `Select Case True
            Case .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(OUTSOURCED)"
                findTerm = "OUTSOURCED"
            Case Else
             .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "No"
                findTerm = "COMING UP…"
            Case Else
             .Cells(sourceRowNum, 4).Value = "(DESIGN ONLY)"
                findTerm = "DESIGN; DESIGN ONLY ORDERS"
            Case Else
             .Cells(sourceRowNum, 5).Value = "Yes"
                findTerm = "DESIGN;PRODUCTION/ACTUAL ORDERS"`

Comment: @Jakebnda if you could edit your post to include your new code; it's difficult to read in-line as a comment.  It looks like you have `Case Else` within a line with another case's criterion, which would not be correct.  The line order would be `Select Case` break; `Case 1` break; `Case 2` break; `Case Else` break; `End Select` break;

Comment: Fixed that issue, now im running into "Object variable or With block variable not set" and its highlighting `Dim destWS As Worksheet:  destWS = DestWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @Jakebnda doh, both of those should be `Set destWS =` and `Set sourceWS =`.

Comment: That seems to work, but its only copying over one row and it's the first row that has a "No" in the E Column... Im stumped lol

Comment: @Jakebnda you've stepped through your code?  I see your edit and I'm not seeing anything glaringly incorrect... it is possible there is an issue with the data not being like for like, e.g. `Trim(Range.Value) = "(OUTSOURCED)"` to remove leading/final spaces in case there are manual entries.

Comment: @Jakebnda I just ran the code and go all items to be move, as expected.  Note that you may want to have `AND` for your cases, since the first case met appends the line.  Will update post with image/code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247228/discussion-between-jakebnda-and-cyril).